# Is peer to peer possible with python's asyncore?

Tags: python, asyncore

"This module provides the basic infrastructure for writing asynchronous socket service clients and servers."
http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html#module-asyncore

If I want a non- client-server architecture, such as peer to peer, can asynchat/asyncore still do the job, or does it force a client-server paradigm?

Comment: The only thing that differentiates a `client` from a `server` is whether or not they accept incoming connections or not.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson And that servers don't initiate connections to clients. Let's say there are 5 peers in the network. The peer who joined third initiated 2 client connections, and started a server/listener that received 2 client connections. To broadcast using asyncore, peer #3 has to broadcast **as a server** to 2 peers, and message **as a client** to 2 others. In "true" P2P, you'd broadcast on all sockets indistinctively. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

By the very definition peer to peer implies direct connectivity, ommiting the idea of central server (at least for the sake of sending data, it still may be used to set up users together for example). And peer to peer doesn't differ much from peer-server communication at it's core - it's a socket communicating between A and B.
Of course running it peer to peer instead via server comes with certain drawbacks, for example you will have to negotiate NAT between peers to figure out which one will be the host, and which one will connect to it. You also need something in place for the case where both users are behind NAT.